# Daily delete files from Google Cloud Firebase Storage bucket that end with .png

Tags: javascript, node.js, firebase, google-cloud-functions, google-cloud-storage

I want to run a Firebase Cloud Function scheduler that once per day deletes all files in a specific bucket that end with `.png`.

This is what I have tried:

```
// The Cloud Functions for Firebase SDK to create Cloud Functions and setup triggers.
const functions = require('firebase-functions');

// The Firebase Admin SDK to access Cloud Firestore.
const admin = require('firebase-admin');
admin.initializeApp();

exports.scheduledFunctionCrontab = functions.pubsub.schedule('0 0 * * *')
  .timeZone('Europe/Amsterdam') 
  .onRun((context) => {
  console.log('This will be run every day at midnight in NL!');

  const bucketName = '<myBucketName>'; //where I replaced this with my actual bucketname
  const filename = '*.png';

  // Imports the Google Cloud client library
  const {Storage} = require('@google-cloud/storage');

  // Creates a client
  const storage = new Storage();

  async function deleteFile() {
    // Deletes the file from the bucket
    await storage.bucket(bucketName).file(filename).delete();
    console.log(`gs://${bucketName}/${filename} deleted.`);
  }

  deleteFile().catch(console.error);
  return null;
});
```

But I get a `message: 'No such object: <myBucketName>/*.png'` error. It seems the * is not picked up by the JavaScript API. With gsutil, this wildcard does work. When I enter the full name of an object, it is deleted successfully according to the scheduled time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Alright, so with the information from @jarmod, I updated the code and got it working as follows:

```
// The Cloud Functions for Firebase SDK to create Cloud Functions and setup triggers.
const functions = require('firebase-functions');

// The Firebase Admin SDK to access Cloud Firestore.
const admin = require('firebase-admin');
admin.initializeApp();

exports.scheduledFunctionCrontab = functions.pubsub.schedule('0 0 * * *')
  .timeZone('Europe/Amsterdam') 
  .onRun((context) => {
  console.log('This will be run every day at midnight in NL!');
  /**
   * TODO(developer): Uncomment the following lines before running the sample.
   */
  const bucketName = '<myBucketName>'; //where I replaced this with my actual bucketname

  // Imports the Google Cloud client library
  const {Storage} = require('@google-cloud/storage');

  // Creates a client
  const storage = new Storage();

  async function deleteFile(filename) {
    // Deletes the file from the bucket

    await storage.bucket(bucketName).file(filename).delete();
    console.log(`gs://${bucketName}/${filename} deleted.`);
  }

  async function listAndDeleteFiles() {
    // Lists files in the bucket
    const [files] = await storage.bucket(bucketName).getFiles();

    console.log('Files:');
    files.forEach(file => {
      console.log(file.name);
      if (file.name.endsWith(".png")) {
        deleteFile(file.name);
      }
      
    });
  }  

  listAndDeleteFiles().catch(console.error);
  return null;
});
```

Answer (score 2):

You can't do this with most cloud storage APIs. They generally don't support wildcards. The `gsutil` CLI is doing the file matching for you but under the covers it's using the API and matching the results to `*.png`.

So, use [getFiles()](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/listing-objects#code-samples) and do the pattern matching in your code to create a list of matching files.